# Error accessing AppFabric Cache

Tags: caching, appfabric

Im trying to get the Appfabric Cache running with IIS7 using an MVC asp.net project.
Using the XML-configuration provider in a shared directory.

I can access the AppFabric Cache when using the cassini webserver (My local administrator account).

When using IIS ("ApplicationPoolIdentity") I can not get it to work, and I get the standard message that it can not connect to the host.

I have tried to grant access to different users (APPPOOL\name, NETWORKservice, Everyone and so on) to the cache but I get this null exception everytime.

> PS C:> Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount "Everyone"
>
> Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount : Object reference not set to an instance of an
>      object.
>      At line:1 char:32
>      + Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount <<<<  Everyone
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccou
>      nt], NullReferenceException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>      System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.Applicat
>      ionServer.Caching.Commands.GrantCacheAllowedClientAccountCommand

I have two almost identical developer machines using win7 x64 (domain connected) where the error is the same on both computers.

But at my home computer (which is not domain connected) it works  as expected with the same installation settings, same shared directory.

What I have done so far:

- Reinstalled appfabric cache twice
- Reconfigured the Cache to use another directory
- Set configuration directory share, full access to Everyone
- Security permissions for the directory, full access to Everyone.

Is there a way to go deeper and debug this error message or a solution to fix it?

[image: Error from appfabric cache powershell]

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>  <configSections>
>    <section name="dataCache"     
>      type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSection,
>      Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" />
> </configSections>
> <dataCache size="Small">
>  <caches>
>    <cache consistency="StrongConsistency" name="default" minSecondaries="0">
>      <policy>
>        <eviction type="Lru" />
>        <expiration defaultTTL="10" isExpirable="true" />
>    </policy>
>   </cache>
>  </caches>
>  <hosts>
>    <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
>      hostId="1556989554" size="3003" leadHost="true" account="DOM\vitcpu7$"
>      cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="vitcpu7.office.domain.se"
>      cachePort="22233" />
> </hosts>
> <deploymentSettings>
>   <deploymentMode value="RoutingClient" />
> </deploymentSettings>
> </dataCache>
> </configuration>
> ```

Answer (score 10):

It´s because it is setup in a domain environment and  the "Remote Registry"-service was not started. Since my home computer in a workgroup,  did not need "Remote Registry" started its the combined which AppFabric cache needs this to make most changes in powershell.

[More information at msdn social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/velocity/thread/e977c98d-32e6-4b58-8947-6248cdcf5020)

Comment: one may also have to start a new powershell session after starting the service to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Kiteloop, need to start "Remote Registry" and run the "Caching Admin Powershell Windows" as Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For build in accounts simply use the command in this format

Grant-CacheAllowedClientAccount -Account "DOMAIN1\Server1$"

More at this MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921012.aspx

Comment: did it really need this answer?